# A command in MySql to increment by one the ID column

Tags: mysql

This is my case:

[image]

What I want is to increment all rows after the raw of 135th by one, for e.g: 136,137.
I have been trying to make some updates but none of them works.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Do you have an `AUTOINCREMENT` column and you want to "reset" that column and re-create IDs for the data?  This would be a strange thing to want to do, what specifically is the problem you're looking to solve?

Comment: Also, pls show an sql statement you tried and the errors / unexpected results you got.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because the consecutive ID's already exist. What you could do is first increasing you ID's to non-existing values, then decrease them to the values you want.

#### Example

1. Increase the ID's with a bigger amount than the highest ID, i.e.:

   UPDATE tablename SET id = id + 100000 WHERE id >= 135;
2. Then decrease them to the values you wanted (in this case 100.000 minus 1)

   UPDATE tablename SET id = id - 99999 WHERE id >= 100000;
3. Reset the auto increment

   ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `id` = `id` + 1 WHERE `id` >= 135 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```